# How to create short and long code on mobile studio in marketing cloud?

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I want to know that how can we create short/long code on mobile studio salesforce marketing cloud org And what is the process ?
I will search on it google but i can't understand properly so can you please help me in that?